# Plot in python that updates on keyboard hit

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've been struggling to achieve something that is trivial in Octave: to produce a series of plots, that change when I hit a key. Here's my octave code sample.

```
x = [1:10];
for c=1:3
    plot(x,c.*x);
    hold off;
    input('a');
end
```

When I try to do the same in python, I realized that python matplotlib has the save function, which puts it in non-blocking mode, and so I have to close the figure using a mouse, for the next figure to be produced. And the next figure is at a random other location on the screen. How can I get python to imitate the above behavior? I've tried various combinations of ion(), ioff(), plt.show(), plt.draw(), but haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something fancier if you want, using mpl_connect

First import pylab

```
from pylab import *
```

Then define an updateData function that can be connected to the figure canvas.

```
i = 1
def updateData(event):
    global i,x
    i +=1
    y = i*x
    data.set_data(x,y)
    ylim(y[0],y[-1])
    draw()
```

`i` and `x` are global variables in this case. (This could be treated in better way, this is just an example!)

Then, create you plot and connect with your defined function.

```
f = figure()
data, = plot(x,x)
i=1
f.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event",updateData)
show()
```

Whenever you hit any key in the keyboard (When the figure window is selected) the function `updateData` is called, `i` is incremented and the plot updated.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I hope there is another approach. This method has the computation, event-handling, and plotting all entangled in a single function. The octave/matlab has distinct commands for each.